# Implementing a generator in C++0x

Tags: c++, c++11, generator

The python keyword `yield` has been a great conceptual abstraction for me, allowing me to distill the important parts of an algorithm to human-readable form. We have previously discussed:

[Python generators in various languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451304/python-generators-in-various-languages)

where an answer was given for a windows only library in C++. In addition I've found another example using a funky macro expansion in the question:

[Generators in C++ — invalid use of nonstatic data member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604699/generators-in-c-invalid-use-of-nonstatic-data-member)

The edge of my computer science knowledge tells me that a yield function has [something to do with co-routines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644592/implementing-generator-support-in-a-custom-language) and monads, but I'm not quite how this fits into what C++ or C++0x can accomplish.

It seems that in C++, without the using of a macro-expansion or a windows only fiber (thread), `yeild` can not be implemented. Is this true? Does the question change with the additional language features of C++0x?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can map `yield` python mechanism to C++ iterators.

See [Boost Function Input Iterator](http://www.boost.org/libs/iterator/doc/function_input_iterator.html) and the example:

> The Function Input Iterator allows for creating iterators that encapsulate a nullary function object and a state object which tracks the number of times the iterator has been incremented. A Function Input Iterator models the InputIterator concept and is useful for creating bounded input iterators.
>
> Like the Generator Iterator, the Function Input Iterator takes a function that models the Generator concept (which is basically a nullary or 0-arity function object). Each increment of the function Function Input Iterator invokes the generator function and stores the value in the iterator. When the iterator is dereferenced the stored value is returned.

Comment: This is not quite the same as Python's `yield`.

Comment: @KennyTM: different syntax, same concept.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: How do you do http://users.softlab.ece.ntua.gr/~ttsiod/yield.html *easily* with Boost Function Input Iterator? I mean easily, i.e. no need to require the user to know what state should be saved to the genertor functor.

Comment: @KennyTM I tried and must admit it's not trivial to replicate that Python code in C++. On practice, however, I'd use http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/next_permutation.html

Answer (score 3):

`yield` is basically a way to implement a restricted form of coroutines.

If you want to badly enough, you can (as in, "people have") implemented relatively complete coroutines in C using `setjmp` and `longjmp`. In C++, you can *probably* do the same, though I'm not entirely sure. The problem with C++ becomes one of deciding what dtors to execute when. Offhand, I think the answer is that dtors shouldn't be affected by the coroutine usage, but I haven't really thought about it much. Assuming that's correct, then roughly the same code should probably work for C++ as for C.

C++0x adds full support for threads and such. Though it can be clumsy and/or increase overhead, pretty much anything you could hope to do with fibers, you can also do with threads. As such, it would support the idiom quite a bit more directly, so implementation would be quite a bit easier.

Comment: `longjmp` doesn't mix well with C++ at all, as you mentioned.

Comment: What? Why longjump doesn't mix well with C++ (btw I didn't get the impression that Jerry was saying what you say he is).

Comment: I've heard of coroutines being programmed in C++ by use of a callstack object, and _very_ carefully coded functions.

Comment: On Linux (and possibly other Posix systems, because it was part of Posix until 2008), I think makecontext and swapcontext are the right functions for this.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I've never used generators myself but from what I understand you want some function that returns an iterator that implements the increment operator ++. Pseudo code:

```
int f(int x) {
    for(int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
        yield(i);
    }
}

for(iterator it = make_generator(std::bind(f, 5));
    it != generator_end();
    ++it)
{
    do_something(*it);
}

// iterator specialized for the return type of f
template<typename T>
iterator<T> make_generator(Function<T (void)> f) {
    ...
}
```

You will need to construct the iterator from pointer to function `f`, and you can pass any arguments to `f` by using `std::bind`.

Now at each iteration you need to effectively call `f` at some point and the function `yield` must do some stack manipulation to save the current stack, return the yielded value and restore the stack when the function gets called again. You only need to save the stack up to the point where f is called (no need for entire stack), but this could be tricky to implement. You'll probably have to save the stack pointer before you call f, then make a copy of the contents of (previous stack pointer..current stack pointer) somewhere.